# Sink Faucet Handle Removal

Tags: faucet, removal

[image][image]I need to remove the base of the broken-off handle on the right in order to put in a new handle. The base does turn back and forth a little but seems to be only for the purpose of adjusting the location of the handle. I confirmed this by trying it on the left handle. Is anyone familiar with this kind of handle?

[image]

Comment: Any chance of getting a picture/pictures of the bottom side of the faucet under the countertop?